# Need a good database design for this situation

Tags: database-schema

I am making an application for a restaurant.

For some food items, there are some add-ons available - e.g. Toppings for Pizza.

My current design for Order Table-

FoodId || AddOnId

If a customer opts for multiple addons for a single food item (say Topping and Cheese Dip for a Pizza), how am I gonna manage?

Solutions I thought of -

1. Ids separated by commas in AddOnId column (Bad idea i guess)
2. Saving Combinations of all addon as a different addon in Addon Master Table.
3. Making another Trans table for only Addon for ordered food item.

Please suggest.

PS - I searched a lot for a similar question but cudnt find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your relationship works like this:

(1 Order) has (1 or more Food Items) which have (0 or more toppings).

The most detailed structure for this will be 3 tables (in addition to Food Item and Topping):

1. Order
2. Order to Food Item
3. Order to Food Item to Topping

Now, for some additional details.  Let's start flushing out the tables with some fields...

1. Order

   1. OrderId
   2. Cashier
   3. Server
   4. OrderTime
2. Order to Food Item

   1. OrderToFoodItemId
   2. OrderId
   3. FoodItemId
   4. Size
   5. BaseCost
3. Order to Food Item to Topping

   1. OrderToFoodItemId
   2. ToppingId
   3. LeftRightOrWhole

Notice how much information you can now store about an order that is not dependent on anything except that particular order?

While it may appear to be more work to maintain more tables, the truth is that it structures your data, allowing you many added advantages... not the least of which is being able to more easily compose sophisticated reports.

Comment: the solution was always but this has cleared my head on one way of doing it and for now its serves purpose. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You want to model two many-to-many realtionships by the sound of it.

i.e. Many products (food items) can belong to many orders, and many addons can belong to many products:

```
Orders
    Id

Products
    Id

OrderLines
    Id
    OrderId
    ProductId

Addons
    Id

ProductAddons
    Id
    ProductId
    AddonId
```

Option 1 is certainly a bad idea as it breaks even first normal form.

Answer (score 2):

why dont you go for many-to-many relationship.
situation: one food can have many toppings, and one toppings can be in many food.

you have a food table and a toppings table and another FoodToppings bridge table.

this is just a brief idea. expand the database with your requirement

[image]

Comment: The Id in 'FoodToppings' is Primary key. Did the diagram in a hurry.

Comment: This structure is good for giving toppings available for a particular food.  The question seems to be more about placing an order, right?

Nice diagram, though!

Answer (score 1):

You're right, first one is a bad idea, because it is not compliant with normal form of tables and it would be hard to maintain it (e.g. if you remove some addon you would need to parse strings to remove ids from each row - really slow).

Having table you have already there is nothing wrong, but the primary key of that table will be (foodId, addonId) and not foodId itself.

Alternatively you can add another "id" not to use compound primary key.